# how to multiply time with double as in calculate the overtime payment

Tags: mysql

i want to multiply over time hours with price for hour as

```
select 83 * overtime from att where Eid= 5;
```

the overtime inserted as time format and the the result for this
  3320000 
its actually only 4 hours overtime 
it is HR application to calculate salary and overtime

Comment: `mysql` <> `sql-server`. Please only tag the RDBMS you're using. You might also consider providing some sample data and expected results.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL? You just need to convert overtime to hours before making calculations. And we can't help on that since we don't know how conversion is made

Comment: sorry for that, I am using MySQL and the answer down is what I seek for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in several ways. To do that, you can convert your time to seconds and then you can get total hours.
You can do that like this:
If you are using **mySql**:

```
select 83 * ((time_to_sec(overtime) / 60) / 60) from att where Eid = 5;
```

If you are using **SQL Server**:

```
SELECT 83 * ((DATEDIFF(SECOND, 0, overtime) / 60) / 60) FROM att WHERE Eid = 5
```